# Mapping SAN to cluster nodes

Tags: windows, storage-area-network, failovercluster, cluster-shared-volumes

I have mapped a block of space from SAN to 3 cluster nodes (2012r2)as below:

1. 2 ports from each node have been mapped to the same share on SAN for redundancy.
2. MPIO has been configured on all nodes
3. SAN share has been successfully added to all nodes .

Question:

Should I see the same contants of that SAN share on all nodes, currently I created some files from 1 node, but I could not see those files in that share from other nodes?

Any idea why?

Comment: You don't say what type of cluster this is, but if it's a Hyper-V cluster you'll need to create a Cluster Shared Volume for the shared storage that you've mounted to each server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh god, you've not have you? You've just caused immediate, irretrievable data loss sorry.

NTFS isn't a cluster-aware file system, you need something to act as a lock manager too.

MS Cluster Services can do some of this for you but they won't be active/active as I suspect you want - for that you might needs something like Symantec Storage Foundation which uses it's own file system for this.

Either way that 'share' is dead, you'll need to wipe it.

Comment: What is the proper way to map a SAN storage to windows node in cluster?

Comment: Using a cluster-aware file system, as Chopper3 said. Since they're Windows hosts, you have to use MS Clustering Service, or a 3rd-party clustering solution.

Comment: Good thing is that it is a dev environment, no data loss